# Solve why .htaccess is not working for my xamp server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

I am hosting a website using XAMPP on Windows, and within the main directory I have a `.htaccess` file with the following code:

```
# Disable index view
Options -Indexes

<Files ".env">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

This is intended to enhance the security of sensitive files of my website, for some reason the only part working is the `Options -Indexes` but I am still able to browse the s=.htaccess and .env files with ease, and my `.htaccess` is in the correct directory.

I would appreciate help or a clue on how to resolve this issue?

I also tried switching between

```
Order Allow,Deny 
Deny from all
```

and

```
Require all denied
```

to no avail, I also checked my error logs and do not see anything of note.

Furthermore I also included the following in my `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` and my `C:\xampp\apache\conf\original\httpd.conf` files.

```
<Directory "DIR">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Welcome! A short friendly hint, since you are a first time poster: please learn how to use the code formatting features the edit form offers. Check the meaning of the icons in the tool bar above the input area where you post or edit your question. That helps others to read, therefore understand your question. Even now you should hit that "edit" button below your question and enhance its readability. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, ill keep that in mind in future.

Comment: "I am still able to browse the s=.htaccess" - A default install of XAMPP will normally block access to `.htaccess` files in the server config (as will "most", if not all, shared server environments), so you shouldn't even need to implement this yourself. (Unless this behaviour has changed in more recent versions of XAMPP?) If you have your own server then you would block access to `.htaccess` files in the server config, not in `.htaccess` itself.

Comment: How do i go about blocking access to .htaccess files in the server config?And what about the .env file?

Comment: Basically the same as what you are currently doing in `.htaccess`! (But as I mentioned above, XAMPP _should_ already have something like that in the server config.) The same process for `.env` files. _Aside:_ However, you should not mix old/deprecated/Apache 2.2 `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` directives with the new/recommended/Apache 2.4 `Require` directive(s). (I'm not sure why you have?) You should not be editing the `...\original\httpd.conf` file - that is intended to be documentation of the "original" file, it is not processed.

Comment: However, you stated in another comment (on the answer since deleted) "...the apache access logs there are no attempts to access the .env or ht files" - yes, that is a problem. Apache should see the request. If not then you can't block it! Are you sure you are looking in the correct access log? Are you accessing the file via the Apache webserver? (In other words, through a browser using the HTTP protocol, eg. `http://localhost/.htaccess`? And not simply using the filesystem?)

Comment: You are using XAMPP in a local development environment, so there shouldn't be much else getting in the way... presumably you don't have Nginx or some other webserver installed that might be catching the request or acting as a proxy in front of Apache?!